# Python: compare two strings retain difference from one end

Tags: python, string, compare, substring

Beginner here, and haven't found an answer for this question though some are similar.

If I have two strings:

```
s1 = 'abcdefghijk'
s2 = 'abcdefghi'
```

How do I get `'jk'` as an output? `'abcdefghi'` must first match, and then I get the difference on the end.

The next after this (which I may be able to figure out if I get the first question answered) is what if `s2 = 'cdefghi'` and I still want output to be only `'jk'` not `'ab'` and `'jk'`.

Comment: I don't think your problem is fully specified. What should be returned if there are non-common parts to the strings, e.g. `"abc"` and `"xyz"`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: 'abc' and 'xyz' would not return anything. only if something matches, I want to see what is at the end of s1 that isn't on s2. In the case I'm looking at s2 would either end at the same place as s1 but will never be longer and go further at the end than s1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the first index of `s2` in `s1` with `find()`, i.e.:

```
def after(s1, s2):
    index = s1.find(s2)
    # return None if s2 is not part of s1
    # or if there are no characters behind s2 in s1
    if index != -1 and index + len(s2) < len(s1):
        return s1[index + len(s2):]
    else:
        return None

s1 = "abcdefghijk"
s2 = "cdefghij"

print(after(s1, s2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string method `index` to find the start of the substring, then add the length of the substring to get where you want to start taking your extra difference from.

```
base = 'abcdefghijk'
sub = 'abcdefghi'

def extra(base, sub):
    start = base.index(sub)
    end = start + len(sub)
    return base[end:]

extra(base, sub)
```

A `ValueError` will be thrown here if `sub` is not a substring, and you can choose to do what you wish in that case.

Edit: based on your comment on your question, to return nothing - I'm guessing you mean maybe an empty string - do:

```
def diff(base, sub):
    try:
        start = base.index(sub)
        end = start + len(sub)
        return base[end:]
    except ValueError:
        return ''
```

Whether you use `find` or `index` here probably depends on what you're actually wanting to use this for.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, case s1 = 'abcdefghijk' s2 = 'abcdefghi' , the below would work too.

```
>>> set(s1) - set(s2)
{'j', 'k'}
>>> ''.join( set(s1) - set(s2))
'jk'
```

So basically set logic can be applied on strings to extract overlapping and non-overlapping parts of the mentioned strings.

For more info ... https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

But for the 2nd case , @user3760780 suggestion seems to be the best fit.